# How to shift an interval when using the C++ Boost interval container library (ICL)?

Tags: c++, boost, intervals, boost-icl

How do I shift a discrete_interval using the Boost interval container library?

i.e. I want to subtract integer c from the lower() of the interval and from the upper() of the interval? Obviously I could create a new interval, but I'm looking for the canonical way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way is to construct a new interval and assign it to your interval because [`boost::lcl::discrete_interval`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/icl/doc/html/boost/icl/discrete_interval.html) is immutable (apart from the assignment operator). So to shift an interval you have to create a new interval with the desired lower and upper bounds and assign it to the old interval.

```
boost::icl::discrete_interval<int> interval;
interval = boost::icl::discrete_interval<int>::closed(3, 4);
```

Comment: well at least I'm not going to spend anymore time trying to find a solution isn't there. 

Even if intervals are immutable, why not have a function which takes an interval and a constant of type T (of int in your case)  and returns a new interval with the interval shifted over? 

This isn't hard to write, but it seems like it would make sense to have something like this in the API.